# ¿Como se le da tamaño a los componentes dentro de un layout?

Tags: java

Tengo entendido que cuando se usan los Layouts y no el layout por defecto,estos tienen unos tamaños que se ajustan al tamaño de la ventana.El problema es que cuando uso un Layout,a veces tengo por ejemplo los botones muy grandes y me gustaria ajustar su tamaño de acuerdo a la necesidad.El tema es que uso el metodo setSize() y no se pone el tamaño indicado.
Como podria hacer para cambiar el tamaño a uno que yo crea conveniente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el metodo [setBounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

```
etiqueta1 = new JLabel("Nombre: ");
etiqueta1.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 50);
etiqueta1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
panel.add(etiqueta1);
```

Comment: ahh pensaba que dentro de un marco con layouts no se podia usar ese metodo,muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Pues si, se puede usar y se debe usar, si ves que es la respuesta adecuada contempla marcarla como correcta, por favor. Gracias.

Comment: Si amigo,le di ya pero como no tengo reputacion no cuenta mi voto

Comment: @SantiagoSalinas el aceptar la respuesta se hace dando clic en la palomita gris que esta al lado izquierdo de la misma y para esta acción no requieres reputación.